# Stripe Payment Intents API: How to confirm the payment on the server side?

Tags: stripe-payments

Before migrating to the Payment Intents API the user's credit card payment was confirmed and charged on the server side using the token (received from stripe.createToken) after the purchase has been completed. This gave us the possibility not to confirm the payment in case any errors happens.

Now, with the Payment Intents API the payment confirmation happens already on the client side (stripe.confirmCardPayment) which is a problem in case an error happens on the server side while completing the purchase as the credit card has already been charged. A refund is not valid solution your Stripe fees won't be refunded.

How can we implement card payments with the Payment Intents API but confirm the payment at the final end of the purchase (as in the legacy workflow)? Or how can we prevent the credit card from being charged in case an error occurs during the checkout workflow?
Unfortunately, we couldn't find a solution to this problem in the documentation.

Help appreciated!

Here are the docs: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our case, we wanted to authenticate the card payment at the end directly after making the charge. The Stripe support was able to help us with the following answer:

As I understand you would like to authenticate the payment at the end directly after making the charge. There is a solution to this, with the capture_method being set to Manual -  https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-capture_method. What this would mean is, that the charge will be made and the user / client would be able to confirm the payment afterwards in the Dashboard directly.

This method is called Auth and Capture. Place a hold on a card to reserve funds now but only capture them after your business completes the service. When a payment is authorized, the bank guarantees the amount and holds it on the customer’s card for up to seven days, or two days for in-person payments using Terminal. You can find more information along with the API's under this Link: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/capture-later#authorize-only

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is modeled via "manual confirmation" of a PaymentIntent: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-synchronously.

It isn't Stripe's recommended integration. The recommended approach is to confirm client-side and listen to webhooks for payment confirmation.

This is because with manual confirmation, there is a higher chance of customer "drop off" where they authenticate your PaymentIntent on your webpage but close it out, meaning you lose your client->server roundtrip, leaving your payment unconfirmed (eventhough the customer thinks they authenticated hence paid).

Additionally, manual confirmation only works for card type payments, it is not supported for other payment methods based in other regions like iDEAL or SEPA Debit etc.